# Make async calls in express server app.get

Tags: express

I'm making an Express server that translates videos from a youtube playlist into an xml podcast feed. My app.get returns some generated xml:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    return res.send(xml(myXmlContent, { declaration: true }));
})
```

I need to fill myXmlContent with some data including the video IDs in the youtube playlist. I can use the youtube API to get those video IDs, but it's not synchronous. It returns the IDs in a callback.

How can I wait until I get the results back before returning from app.get? I'm probably going about this the wrong way, as timeouts will probably be an issue. Any suggestions how I can achieve dynamic xml generation that relies on async calls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I wait until I get the results back before returning from app.get?

You don't "wait" in Javascript.  Instead, you send the response inside the callback when you get the result from the other API call.  This is how asynchronous development works in node.js.

> How can I wait until I get the results back before returning from app.get?

You don't.  You can return from `app.get()` just fine before you've sent the response.  That doesn't mean you're done processing at all.  `app.get()` (and express middleware too) are designed to you can use asynchronous operations in order to get the data for the response.  You just return and then sometime later when your async operations are done and you have the data you need, you send the response.

> I'm probably going about this the wrong way, as timeouts will probably be an issue.

This is not the wrong way.  But, if your external API is really slow, then you may have to worry about either Express timeouts or browser timeouts.  The express timeouts, you can configure.  The browser timeouts are not as easy to deal with.  If it takes so long to get the results that you are hitting a browser timeout, then you probably need to rethink how you're doing things because any ordinary user will give up on a page request or button press anyway if it takes as long as a browser timeout.

There are a couple options for sending the data once you get it.  Since you don't show the external API you're using and how it works, we can't be very specific.  But generally, you do these kinds of things:

1. You put the `res.send()` inside the asynchronous completion callback from your other API.
2. You pipe the results of your other operation into the response.
3. You use promises to get a notification of completion on your other API and put the `res.send()` inside the promise's `.then()` handler.

As an example:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    rp(someURL).then(result => {
        // do some processing of result into finalData
        res.send(finalData);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(501);
    });
});
```

Comment: Works great. Not sure why I assumed you always had to have the res.send call in a return statement (i.e. "return res.send(finalData)"), but it's working for me just as you explained. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeMiller - You only do `return res.send()` when you're trying to exit the function and prevent other code after it from running.  My example doesn't need that since `res.send()` is the last line of code to execute anyway.  express does not not pay attention to any return value from the request handler so there's no obligation to return anything. `return res.send()` is just done as needed for code flow control reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using async and await for your result.

```
app.post('/page', async(req, res) => {
  const content = await mycontent //result you are waiting for
  res.send(content)
});
```